# Is it a problem of stability of the matrix calculation in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I recently encountered a problem of the inaccuracy of the matrix product/multiplication in NumPy. See my example below also here https://trinket.io/python3/6a4c22e450

```
import numpy as np

para = np.array([[ 3.28522453e+08, -1.36339334e+08, 1.36339334e+08],
    [-1.36339334e+08,  5.65818682e+07, -5.65818682e+07],
    [ 1.36339334e+08, -5.65818672e+07,  5.65818682e+07]])

in1 = np.array([[ 285.91695469],
    [ 262.3       ],
    [-426.64380594]])

in2 = np.array([[ 285.91695537],
    [ 262.3       ],
    [-426.64380443]])

(in1 - in2)/in1
>>> array([[-2.37831286e-09],
    [ 0.00000000e+00],
    [ 3.53925214e-09]])
```

The difference between `in1` and `in2` is very small, which is ~10^-9

```
res1 = para @ in1
>>> array([[-356.2361908 ],
    [ 443.16068268],
    [-180.86068344]])

res2 = para @ in2
>>> array([[ 73.03147125],
   [265.01131439],
   [ -2.71131516]])
```

but after the matrix multiplication, why does the difference between the output `res1` and `res2` change so much?

```
(res1 - res2)/res1
>>> array([[1.20500857],
   [0.40199723],
   [0.98500882]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug; it is to be expected with a matrix such as yours.

Your matrix (which is symmetric) has one large and two small eigenvalues:

```
In [34]: evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(para)

In [35]: evals
Out[35]: array([-1.06130078e-01,  1.00000000e+00,  4.41686189e+08])
```

Because the matrix is symmetric, it can be diagonalized with an orthonormal basis.  That just means that we can define a new coordinate system in which the matrix is diagonal, and the diagonal values are those eigenvalues. The effect of multiplying the matrix by a vector in these coordinates is to simply multiply each coordinate by the corresponding eigenvalue, i.e. the first coordinate is multiplied by -0.106, the second coordinate doesn't change, and the third coordinate is multiplied by the large factor 4.4e8.

The reason you get such a drastic change when multiplying the original matrix `para` by `in1` and `in2` is that, in the new coordinates, the third component of the transformed `in1` is *positive*, and the third component of the transformed `in2` is *negative*.  (That is, the points are on opposite sides of the 2-d eigenspace associated with the two smaller eigenvalues.) There are several ways to find these transformed coordinates; one is to compute inv(V)@x, where V is the matrix of eigenvectors:

```
In [36]: np.linalg.solve(evecs, in1)
Out[36]: 
array([[ 5.64863071e+02],
       [-1.16208620e+02],
       [ 8.55527517e-07]])

In [37]: np.linalg.solve(evecs, in2)
Out[37]: 
array([[ 5.64863070e+02],
       [-1.16208619e+02],
       [-2.71381169e-07]])
```

Note the different signs of the third components.  The values are small, but when you multiply by the diagonal matrix, they are multiplied by 4.4e8, giving 377.87 and -119.86, respectively.  That large change shows up as the results that you observed in the original coordinates.

---

For a rougher calculation: note that the elements of `para` are ~10^8, so multiplication on that order of magnitude occurs when you compute `para @ x`.   It is not surprising then, that given the relative differences between `in1` and `in2` are ~10^-9,  the relative differences of `res1` and `res2` will be ~10^-9 * ~10^8 or ~0.1.  (Your calculated relative errors were [1.2, 0.4, 0.99], so the rough estimate is in the right ballpark.)

Comment: Thanks. What is the intuition? Can you explain in laymen's terms? Here we are calculating A*v.  A small change in v causes a big change in A*v, whereas in degenerated case such as y  = 3 x, when x changes 10%, y changes 10% proportionally. So what is the intuition that makes A*v change dramatically with a slight disturbance in v? Isn't it called instability?

Comment: More precisely, when you calculate A * v in where A is a matrix, v is a vector, you expect that a small relative error in the inputs (v here) should cause a small relative error in the output (namely A*v), right? Or else calculating A * v with floating-point (that is only approximative of real values) would make little sense. Matrix multiplication is known to be stable though,  then why matrix multiplication looks unstable in OP's question?

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a bug ...  numpy is written in C, so this could be an issue of casting number into smaller float, which causes big floating point error in this case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).